# ASPX if Greater Than

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell me how I can re-write this to compare to greater than rather than equal to:

```
if (GetSchoolOrLAID.Equals(1))
```

I want it to be:

```
if (GetSchoolOrLAID.GreaterThan(1))
```

Hope really appreciated..

Comment: "Hope really appreciated": Well I'm sure it'll all come good in the end. Does that help? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an extention method with name as `GreaterThan` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Can you not use the operator?

`if (GetSchoolOrLAID > 1)`

or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

How about an operator?

```
if (GetSchoolOrLAID > 1)
```

Comment: oh good - someone else said the same thing. Thought I might be doing a <planthandonforhead>.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.Compare()` method.